# MixPanel for error monitoring

Tags: android, monitoring, analytics, mixpanel

I am working on an Android Application which is integrated with [MixPanel](https://www.mixpanel.com) for analytics and [BugSnag](https://bugsnag.com/) for error monitoring.

Recently we found crash in the application and as we couldn't find the root cause of the crash we added code to restart the app when the bug occurs. Along with restart, we also started tracking how many times the bug occurs. My preference was to use Bugsnag for the same, but couple of people in the team asked why can't we use MixPanel because we can easily filter out the events with parameters which we sent to MixPanel. But I feel MixPanel shouldn't be used as its specifically for tracking user events. And neither the crash nor the restart happens because of a user event, it just happens randomly.

I would like to hear suggestions/thoughts from the community regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)` in your `Application.onCreate` to set your custom [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) that tracks to MixPanel all the UncaughtExceptions (Crashes) and set properties such as :

```
public class MyExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler;

    public MyExceptionHandler (UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler)
    {
        this.defaultExceptionHandler = defaultExceptionHandler;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception)
    {
        mMixPanelInstance.trackEvent("APP_CRASH", null);
        if (defaultExceptionHandler != null)
        {
            defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, exception);
        }

    }
}


MyApplication.onCreate(...)
{
    UncaughtExceptionHandler currentHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(currentHandler));
}
```